# Gurobi Token server logs in windows machine

Tags: solver, gurobi

Does Gurobi token server v 7.0.1 creates log files in windows machine? If yes what is the default location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token server can write usage logs, but not algorithm logs.  For Windows, the Gurobi token server output is written to the Windows Event Log; this is explained in the section [Starting a token server](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.0/quickstart_windows/starting_a_token_server.html) of the Quick Start Guide.  (For Linux, the Gurobi token server output is written [to the system log](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.0/quickstart_linux/starting_a_token_server.html)).

Comment: Yes, we're are interested in usage logs and it works perfectly. Thanks!